# PHP escape_string returns 0. Register system

Tags: php, database

```
<?php
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbserver = "localhost";
$db = "data";
$con = mysqli_connect($dbserver, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $db);
if($con->connect_error){
    die('Error ' . $con->connect_error);
}
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$id = rand(100, 1000000);
$usernamea = $con->escape_string($username);
$passworda = $con->escape_string($password);
$emaila = $con->escape_string($email);
$ida = $con->escape_string($id);
$sql = "INSERT INTO logindata (usern, passw, email, id) Values('$usernamea', '$passworda', '$emaila', '$ida')";
$con->query($sql);
?>

<html>
<head>
<script Language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">location.replace("../index.php")</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

escape_string only returns 0 in the $sql string.. please help
i am trying to make register system in MySQL PHP Html and other code.. pls help

Comment: Because you didn't check if form is submitted?

Comment: It is, but I fixed it because LocalHost PHPmyadmin string were set to ints and ints were set to strings.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it. Localhost PHPmyadmin had strings converted to ints and ints converted to strings.